# Install new crontab from within vim

Tags: vim, cron

I edit my `crontab` using `vim` (opened via `crontab -e` command).

**How can I update the effective cron table without leaving `vim`?**

For safety reasons `crontab -e` opens a temporary file (check path by pressing <kbd>1</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). When you leave your editor of choice your cron table is checked and if it is valid it will be installed showing the familiar

`crontab: installing new crontab`

Answer (score 2):

While within vim you can run shell commands. Do the following to install the current buffer as your cron table.

`:w`

This will save the current buffer to its file.

`:!crontab %`

This will open a shell and call `crontab` giving the current buffer's file (known to `vim` as `%` by its relative path) as the new cron table to install.

If you don't trust the shell command, maybe try the following commands first:

`:!echo foo` to see the shell and the output `foo`.

`:!echo %` to see the relative path to the buffer's file.